# check two links if both are equal (any condition) PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am working on a website and i am little stuck into one situation , what i want is that to check if the header url is equal to any custom url , if both are same then then the condition should apply,
i added a code but it dosent work for me, however i echo the values of each $variable where my links are stored , here below is my code , which have correct values but it dosent do exactly what i want,

```
$login_page = get_option('workscout_profile_page');
                            $urllinkfi = "192.168.1.50".$variable = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
                            $urllinkse = "192.168.1.50".$variable = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."#tab2"; 
                            $permalinkone = get_permalink();
                            $permalinktwo = get_permalink()."#tab2";
                            $find = array( 'http://', 'https://' );
                            $replace = '';
                            $output = str_replace( $find, $replace, $permalinkone );
                            $outputtwo = str_replace( $find, $replace, $permalinktwo );

                            




                            if($urllinkfi == $output ) { ?>

                                 <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($login_page)); ?>" class="login-btn"><i class="la la-sign-in-alt"></i> <?php esc_html_e('Log In','workscout'); ?></a>

                           <?php }elseif ($urllinkse == $outputtwo) { ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($login_page)); ?>#tab2" class="register-btn"><i class="la la-plus-circle"></i> <?php esc_html_e('Register','workscout'); ?></a>
                           <?php }else{ ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($login_page)); ?>" class="login-btn"><i class="la la-sign-in-alt"></i> <?php esc_html_e('Log In','workscout'); ?></a>
                                     <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($login_page)); ?>#tab2" class="register-btn"><i class="la la-plus-circle"></i> <?php esc_html_e('Register','workscout'); ?></a>
                          <?php  }
```

Comment: So show us what _exactly_ `var_dump($urllinkfi, $output);` outputs then.

Comment: @CBroe as you askede here is my output if i echo $urllinkfi and, $output

Comment: Where is what now? And I specifically asked you to use `var_dump`, so please do that.

Comment: D:\wamp64\www\jobifylocal\wp-content\themes\workscout\header.php:188:string '192.168.1.50/jobifylocal/my-profile/' (length=36) <------------ this is the output of var_dump($urllinkfi, $output);  @CBroe

Comment: That should show _two_ values (and their length), not just _one_.

Comment: so now........?

Comment: Now you would need to explain how you managed to break `var_dump` :-) Even if one of those variables was not even defined in the current scope, at least you should get `null` then in such a case.

Comment: (What kind of writing code is `$urllinkfi = "192.168.1.50".$variable = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` anyway?)